# Layer not aligning after georeferencing using BC Albers

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm currently having trouble with the georeferencer... after what appears to be successful georeferencing, the map image layer does not align to the vector data.

I'm trying to use BC Albers projection (as it's the projection of the original map image as well as the vector dataset). On-the-fly transformation is selected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked that the layer is added with the right CRS: Rightclick -> `Set layer CRS` ? Sometimes QGIS guesses wrong in this step.

Comment: yep, when i look at the coordinate reference system selector, it says it's BC Albers.

Comment: Did you georeference by clicking points in the vector layer, or by adding coordinates read from the map? Maybe the map is in NAD27, which has an offset to NAD83.

Comment: I clicked the points in the vector layer. The map *says* it's 83, and it's at such a large scale that I don't think it would make a difference anyways.

Comment: How much offset do you have? And have you confirmed the vector data against Openstreetmap or Google Imagery via openlayers plugin? Maybe you had selected a point wrong in the vector data, offsetting the resulting picture. I use around 6 to 10 points, if available, and look for the offset calculated for each point. It should not be more then 10pixels.

Comment: It's way way way off: doesn't show up at all in the extent where it should be. After several tries, I don't think it's not a human error during georeferencing, but maybe with the settings. The vector data is correct. The RMS error isn't large for any point.

Comment: shoot, i think it was the wrong projection CRS that the GCPs were recorded in after all... though the projection had been saved to albers. d'oh. thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

If you georeference by clicking points on the image and on the canvas, it is necessary to set the CRS of the georeference output to the **project** CRS. The CRS of the **layers** in the canvas can be different from that.

Unfortunately, the Georeferencer presets the output CRS to the one used last. See this ticket: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7243

Answer (score 0):

Common problem from what i have done.

Methods i use to ensure re-projection is correct:

Check layer CRS through right clicking layer and selecting set layer crs and then by way of double checking.. selecting properties and set layer crs here.

then in settings>project properties>crs.

If still nothing try in the options section of the settings.

If all else consider that the vector data may be wrong.

Comment: Tried it all, with no joy. Pretty sure vector data is not wrong - it's from the BC Government. I feel like maybe it's something I'm doing wrong in the settings... though they seem explanatory enough.